# Create a Song List Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman, knapsack-problem

I would like to create a program that will create randomized set lists for my band; however, I don't want the sets to be completely random. Some songs are better to start a set with, some songs are better to end on. Some songs require changing instruments so I would like to limit the number of switches. It's usually not a good idea to go from a fast song to a slow song, but slow to fast is preferred. We can't play for 180 minutes straight, so I would like to break up the gig into three sets of 50 minutes.

I can imagine the relationship of the songs as a fully-connected, directed graph, with each song as a node and the connections between them being a score representing how good one song would follow the previous, which lends itself to the traveling salesman. But, I don't want the shortest path, I want the best song transitions within a 50 minute set (each song has a duration and the total duration of all songs within the set list must not exceed 50 minutes), which sounds more like a knapsack problem.

Could someone help me out here? What algorithm should I research?

EDIT (MORE INFO):

I have already thought of a function to score a transition between two songs f(s,t) that produces an integer value between 0 and 100, with 100 being the better transition. I also thought about creating nodes for the start of the show ("START"), the end of the show ("END"), and breaks in between ("BREAK 1", "BREAK 2", etc). The function mentioned before can score a transition from "START" to another song or a song to "BREAK 1" to represent opening a set or closing a set given a particular song.

Comment: From my understanding, this problem seems interesting but lacks a few information. We are trying to optimise something but we not quite sure what : what is the relative priority/preference on the different criterias we have : best songs to start with, best songs to end with, equality of the time of the different parts, going from slow to fast... Also, we don't really know much about the inputs : for the ending/songs, how is it described? Can a song be good both as an ending one and a starting one ? Also, do the incrasing-speed criteria apply to the gig or to the different sets ?

Comment: I added a little more information. And yes, a song could be a good opener and also a good closer. The tempo changes are only considered between two songs, not over the course of an entire set or an entire show.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Another additional question : will the generated set contain all the pre-selected songs or should some of them be discarded ?

Comment: Some of them may be discarded. There may be times where we only have a 90 minute show, in which case I would want to generate one set of 90 minutes. In that case, about half the songs will be excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TSP might not be a very good description of this question. The reason being your not actually looking for the best set list, as you are simply looking for a number of good set lists.

That being said, your problem reminds me a lot of using particle filters for trying to locate where something is.

Tweaking the method a fair bit gives something like this:

1. Randomly generate 100 set lists using weighted probability. It might be useful to have some of those picked by hand.
2. Calculate the scores for each set list, then use those as weights to randomly select 10 set lists.
3. For each of those set lists, randomly generate 10 songs using weighted probability. For example, you might use the score of the song as a weight to determine if should you change it or not (low relative score means more likely for the song to be changed).
4. Repeat steps two and three as desired.
5. Pick the current best, or randomly select one of the current 100.

I used an example of 100, but you can use pretty much any sample size under probably a million or so unless you got a lot of time to let it run. Just be careful of how many you select VS how many you generate from those selected. The number selected times the number generated should equal the number you originally started with.

Edit:

Not sure your familiar with weighted probability so I should probably summarize as it's rather important to the algorithm. Say you have songs A-C, with weights 1-3 respectively. One way to handle weighted probability is instead of randomly picking 100 elements from [A,B,C] (which is unweighted), you actually randomly pick 100 elements from [A,B,B,C,C,C]. Since the weight of C is 3x that of A, it is is 3x as likely to be picked.

Ideally, if you're using that method, you should keep the scores as integers, and they should be relatively low (so that the max length of the list to pick the elements from doesn't get too high). If you don't mind loss of precision (which for this case is probably fine), you can also normalize the probabilities and use that create a list that will be much more predictable in terms of how large it is. This can be done by summing the weights, then divide each by the sum, then multiply all of the results by a single number. So for example if you had weights of [1000,10000,100000] instead of 1-3, dividing each by the sum (111000) yields approximately [0.009,0.090,0.901], which times by say 100 (which gives a list size of about 100) and rounding to the nearest whole number gives: [1,9,90] Thus your list from which you randomly choose elements should contain exactly 1 A's, 9 B's and 90 C's. There's a chance that only A would be selected for re-sampling (step 3), but that's rather unlikely, although it would be problematic if it occurred. In which case, you'd probably have to re-run the program. There are ways you could get around that, but you'd end up losing a lot of the randomness of the algorithm.

Oh and adding on to 3) When changing a song, calculate the score for every song that could replace that song. Remove all songs that are of lower weight or perhaps just below some fraction of it's weight*, then use the scores as weights and randomly pick the new song that will replace it (which may actually be the same song if the score is rather high).

*This is optional, but probably not a bad idea to implement if you think it might be useful as you could just set it to below 0.0 * the weight.

Comment: You did a good job explaining this. I'm going to give it a try. It will be a few days before I can have it completely implemented. Thanks for the good answer.

Comment: I've expanded it to include information on how to handle the weighted probabilities. Even if you already know how, it'll help anyone who sees this in the future.

Comment: I implemented the basic premise of this solution. I randomly generate 100 set lists then take the top 10. I call off to a method that will mutate those 10 into 70 other set lists. Then, I fill the remainder of the 100 spots with new random set lists. The current implementation of the mutation method just creates random set lists-I will implement the real mutation method later. Even with all random set lists, I still get good results after 5000 iterations but it takes 5 minutes. When I use "good" sets to create similar but better sets, I can decrease the iterations. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear the algorithm seems to be working well for you. 5000 iterations sounds about right for pure random algorithm. It wouldn't surprise me with even random start values if you start getting good values in under 100 iterations, perhaps even as low as 5-10. Oh, and the changes you made to my original suggestion should work nicely, although 20-30% pure random might be a bit high. Could probably narrow it down to only 1-10%.

Comment: I'll play around with the pure random percentage and see what I get. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, the pure random aspect is mostly to ensure that you don't run into a "bad luck" situation where a series of poor random selections ends up turning "good" to bad. It's rather unlikely, but it can happen. It can also be handled simply by always selecting a certain amount of good choices. Although, as mentioned, that'll impact that overall randomness. Although, perhaps that's not exactly a bad thing.